# Unique array using for-if

Tags: javascript, arrays

would appreciate if anyone could tell me why this isn't working?

```js
function(array){

    var uniqueArray = [];

    for (i=0 ; i < array.length; i++) {

        for (j=0; j < uniqueArray.length; j++){

           if (array[i]===uniqueArray[j]) {
           } else {
              uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
           }
        }
    }

   return uniqueArray;
}
```

I've seen something online about using two more variables:[The count and start variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM1za.png)
But I don't understand why those are necessary. As far as I can tell, mine does the same thing? Nothing if i=j and .push if it doesn't.

Comment: The inner loop will never run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your code you try to add to the unique array while looping it which never happens initially. So you should add to the unique array outside the check loop.

But by my benchmarks using `Set` is the fastest way to get a unique array in JS. Using an array is the slowest - `o(n^2)`.

Using Array's built-in methods like `Array::reduce()` and `Array::includes()` instead of manual looping gives more decent results.

Btw, I find that using a block label is elegant in that case and isn't the label anti-pattern since the label's scope is very local.

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const count = 100000;
    const arr = Array.from({ length: count }, () => Math.random());

    function getUniqueArray(arr) {
        return [...new Set(arr)];
    }

    function getUniqueArray2(arr) {

        const out = [];
        const set = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            const val = arr[i];
            if (val in set) {
                continue;
            }
            out.push(val);
        }
        return out;
    }

    function getUniqueArray3(arr) {

        const out = [];

        input: for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < out.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] === out[j]) {
                    continue input;
                }
            }
            out.push(arr[i]);
        }

        return out;
    }

    function getUniqueArray4(arr) {

        return arr.reduce((unique, item) => {
            unique.includes(item) || unique.push(item);
            return unique;
        }, []);

    }

    // @benchmark using Set
    getUniqueArray(arr);

    // @benchmark using object
    getUniqueArray2(arr);

    // @benchmark using array looping with 1/2 data
    getUniqueArray3(arr.slice(0, arr.length / 2));

    // @benchmark using array methods with 1/2 data
    getUniqueArray4(arr.slice(0, arr.length / 2));

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I do unfortunately have to do iteration for this as the exercise asks me to use === to check for equality, unfortunately forgot to mention this in the question. Thank you regardless as this is very helpful!

Comment: @Codingenthusiast I indeed provided a solution in getUniqueArray3() with `===`. you could accept my answer (the checkbox) if you find it the most useful. in that case i'll be awarded with points and will be motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: Hi sorry yes I did see that I was just explaining why I couldn't use Set. Thanks for explaining about the checkbox also, I am new to this site and didn't know!

Comment: @Codingenthusiast you are welcome. also when you get 15 points of reputation you can also upvote answers (the arrow up) thus giving extra 10 points. So when you accept and upvote an answer it gives 25 points to the answerer (15 for accepting and 10 for upvoting)

Answer (score 1):

Your code can't work because, as noticed by @pilchard, the inner loop will never run: uniqueArray has a starting legth of 0 so it is never cycled ad no values are added to it.
Furthermore, the if condition of the inner loop is also wrong: assuming that the array contains values, every time a non-matching value is found the tested value is appended.

This is a possible solution keeping the code similar to the one you proposed:

```js
function arrayUnique (array){

    let uniqueArray = [];
    let i, j;

    for (i=0 ; i < array.length; i++) {

        for (j=0; j < uniqueArray.length; j++) {

           if (array[i]===uniqueArray[j]) {
                  break;  // ok, the value is already there, let's stop
           }
        }
        
        // if j exceeds the uniqueArray last element index we have not found the searched value...
        if (j == uniqueArray.length) 
          uniqueArray.push(array[i]); // ...so we can add it

    }

   return uniqueArray;
}

const testArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1];
console.log (arrayUnique(testArray1));

const testArray2 = ["a", "aa", "b", "aa", "c", "b"];
console.log (arrayUnique(testArray2));
```

Comment: Add a snippet and some tests for better visualisation and you will get my up vote

Comment: *"Your code can't work"* explaining why would help not only OP but also any future reader.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful! All makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the inner loop, you can use the [array built-in method `includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check whether the element is already in the array or not.

```js
function unique(array) {

    var uniqueArray = [];

    for (i=0 ; i < array.length; i++) {
        // if not already in the array, add that to array
        if (! uniqueArray.includes(array[i]) ) {
          uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    return uniqueArray;
}

// sample run
console.log(unique([1,2,3,2,2]))
console.log(unique([1,1,1,1,1]))
console.log(unique([1,2,3,2,1]))
console.log(unique([]))
```

##### P.S

A better approach would be to use the set (because includes will work fast in hash set).

Comment: Yes this makes sense sorry I didn't mention that the exercise asks me to use === to check for equality. Thank you anyway though as this is still very helpful!